# How do I page counter with divide?

Tags: javascript

I need to make page counter from server data with page limit.
e,g, when I get 8 items from server, I was used like this.

```
let pageCounter = parseInt(TotalData / PageLimit);
```

If PageLimit is 5 items, we might set page Counter as 2 pages.
But, If I use above divide logic, I can get only 1 page.

Who know about this as well?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the `Math.ceil` function.

```
let pageCounter=TotalData < PageLimit ? 1 : Math.ceil(TotalData / PageLimit);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil